# Is it possible to move facebook comments from one URL to another?

Tags: facebook, comments

I mistakenly pointed the facebook comments of one of my pages to the wrong URL. Is there a way to move the comments from one URL to another?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comments will always be associated with that url, but on the comments plugin you can override the url you use by setting the href parameter:

```
<fb:comments href=""http://example.com/page.html"></fb:comments>
```

Comment: I mistakenly associated messages from different URLs with the URL of my homepage. Does this mean I am stuck with them at that URL and can not move the individual messages to more appropriate URLs? Thanks Tom

Comment: I'm afraid that is the case. This is because each URL is a unique object in the Facebook Open Graph. If you have the old reference (link), you can fetch the object (with comments etc.) from Facebook via the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)